# PHP Jquery HTML Array - Multiple Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need upload multiple files to file hosting. I have got PHP file, HTML file with jQuery. I ask you, how to do, HTML variable over Ajax to PHP script? It is array variable multiple file.

HTML:

```
  <div id='attach'>
      <input name='file[]' class='userButton' type='file' multiple='true'/>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type='button' id='pridat_upravene_soubory' class='userButton' value='PŘIDAT SOUBORY'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id='reset_upravene_soubory' type='button' class='userButton' value='RESET'/>
  <br>
<hr>
```

PHP:

```
        foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE && $ochrana == 0){}
            else if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $aErrors[] = 'upload failed_ with error code: ' . $error;
                continue;
            } else {
                $jmeno_souboru = $_FILES["soubory"]["name"][$key];
                $cesta_souboru = "files/$jmeno_souboru";                    
                if (!file_exists($cesta_souboru)) 
                {
                    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["soubory"]["tmp_name"][$key], 'files/clanky/' . $_FILES["soubory"]["name"][$key]))
                        $aErrors[] = 'move_uploaded_file failed';
                }
                $ochrana = 1;
            }
        }
```

jQuery:

```
   $("#pridat_upravene_soubory").click(function() {
   var filedata = $("#attach input[type=file]");
```

I don't know this script

How to make, html variable `name="FILE[]"` over Ajax to PHP script ?

Thanks 
});

Comment: If you want to upload multiple files thought javascript and <form>,you need upload them one by one ,except using HTML5 file API.so you can't get file array in PHP by one request

Comment: I don't use HTML 5. It's work perfect over Ajax, but i don't know how to do it.